# Running batch file with /d option

Tags: windows, command-prompt, installshield

I've been working for some time on the installer for my application (using Installshield), and some time ago I came upon the problem, when batch file, that I called using LaunchApplication failed to execute (to be specific - it executed, but in the wrong directory). I decided to dig this issue up and stumbled upon [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/21/6447771.aspx) article. The problem, it turns out, lies within Autorun registry key, which is defined in following matter:

```
cd /d C:\Blahblah\Yadayada
```

So, before the batch file was actually executed, this command changed directory.
The batch file is most basic one, something like this:

```
:start
foo.exe %1 --bar %2 --baz %3
if errorlevel 1 goto fail
ECHO Success
goto end
fail:
ECHO Fail
:end
```

So, basically this batch file expects that it will be launched from the correct directory, and it's not. I'm append INSTALDIR variable to the batchname in LaunchApplication call, just to be clear, and it works perfectly fine when Autorun key is not set up.
And, well, I finally got to the question - is there any way to provide launch options for individual batch file? I know that providing /d option will render Autorun useless, but it only works only on direct call.

For instance, let's assume that I have batch file with simple 'dir' command (let's call it foo.bat), and my Autorun key is defined as shown above. I run command-prompt with /d option (CMD /d), and then run 'dir' directly I'll get content of the folder I'm currently in (e.g. user folder); BUT, if I launch foo.bat, I'll get contents of C:\Blahblah\Yadayada, because Autorun command will execute first, set default folder, and only after that 'dir' command will be called.

So, personally I see a few options here. First - removing Autorun key, and that would be the most fitting and easiest solution if it had to be applied only for one machine - I can't possibly expect every user to take care of their Autorun key for themselves. Second, which should be applicable for everyone (but which I hadn't tested yet), would be providing path to installation folder as extra parameter to batch file, and then changing directory to that:

```
:start
%4
cd %5
foo.exe %1 --bar %2 --baz %3
...
```

Where %4 would be a disk letter and %5 would be a path. This seems to be a solution, but I find it counterproductive that I have to implicitly change path to the folder, given that it works perfectly well when Autorun key is absent.
So, I was wondering if there's any workaround about this Autorun key problem. Maybe, like I've mentioned in the title, kind of /d option for batch file so that when it runs it will override global option from Autorun and will actually launch from the place it's supposed to launch, or some kind of technique like that? Also, maybe there's some kind of option in LaunchApplication() function I'm not aware of?

Comment: Please - what is the problem? Describe what the batch is supposed to do and what the actual results are. That simple. We don't need (or want) War and Peace with suppoting character-analysis.

Comment: I described my problem and solutions that I've came myself with, so they are not suggested to me second and third times. It's not a War and Peace, I just gave all details which may help to figure this out.

tl;dr:
So, basically my batch should be launched from the correct directory, but it launches from the directory that is set in Autorun registry key. Is there any way to ignore Autorun key when running batch file?